# How can I manually split a model amongst multiple GPU's using pytorch lightning?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, multi-gpu

I have a model that is too large for a single GPU. It has a list of transformers on it that once I run it through the 17th hidden layer, I get a `CUDA out of memory error` I want to therefore run it on multiple GPUs.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import pytorch_lightning as pl

class SplitModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, device1, device2):
        super(SplitModel, self).__init__()

        # Define your model segments
        self.segment1 = #arbitraty in layer
        self.transformers = #a torch.nn.ModuleList of transformers
        self.segment2 = #arbitrary out layer

        self.loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        self.device1 = torch.device('cuda:0')
        self.device2 = torch.device('cuda:1')

    def forward(self, x):
        # Forward pass for segment1 on device1
        x = self.segment1(x)
        for i, transformer in enumerate(self.transformers):
             current_device = '['+''.join("{}: {} ".format(name, next(child.parameters()).device if list(child.parameters()) else "CPU") for name, child in transformer.named_children()) + ']'
              print("iterating through transformer {} on device {}".format(i, current_device))
               attn, ff = transformer
               x = attn(x) + x
               x = ff(x) + x

        # Forward pass for segment2 on device2
        x = self.segment2(x)

        return x

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        inputs, labels = batch

        # Forward pass
        outputs = self(inputs)

        # Calculate loss using segment2 outputs
        loss = self.loss_fn(outputs, labels)

        # Log loss for monitoring (optional)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)

        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
        return optimizer

model = SplitModel()
ddp_strategy = DDPStrategy(find_unused_parameters=True)
Trainer = pl.Trainer(precision="16-mixed", accelerator="cuda", devices=[0, 1], strategy=ddp_strategy)
data_loader = #some dataloader
Trainer.fit(model, data_loader)
```

So then this would be an example output:

```
iterating through transformer 0 on device [0: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 1 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 2 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 3 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 4 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 5 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 6 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 7 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 8 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 9 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 10 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 11 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 12 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 13 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 14 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 15 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 16 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
iterating through transformer 17 on device [0: cuda:0 1: cuda:0]
CUDA out of memory error
```

However, if I were to add this line of code to the forward pass:

```
self.Segment2 = self.Segment2.to(self.device2)
for i, transformer in enumerate(self.transformers):
     if i == 17:
         x = x.to(self.device2)
     if i > 16:
         transformer = transformer.to(self.device2)
    #the rest of iterating through the transformers
return self.Segment2(x).to(self.device1)
```

Then I do not get a `CUDA out of memory error` however, I do get the following error from the backward pass:

```
RuntimeError: grad.device() == bucket_view.device() INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../torch/csrc/distributed/c10d/reducer.cpp":314, please report a bug to PyTorch.
```

I have also looked into sharding the model, instead of manually deciding which parts to put on the GPU. The `strategy` in the `pl.Trainer` module would be `strategy="fsdp"`, I have gotten an error about the batch norm variables one being `torch.cuda.FloatTensor` and `torch.cuda.HalfTensor`.

Is there maybe a way to do this where I create a custom backward layer that changes the device manually?

Comment: line 314 ASSERT is actually " TORCH_INTERNAL_ASSERT(grad.numel() == bucket_view.numel());". Meaning its immutability issue, while both GPUs are are working independently, some common data is getting changed out of band.

Comment: @ShahidRoofiKhan how could I fix this?